# Ordering an SQL query using returned results from a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey i am trying to order an SQL query using returned results from a sub query i.e

```
SELECT tb1.stud_id , tb1.stud_name , (SELECT sum(score) FROM scores WHERE student_id = tb1.
student) AS total_marks 
FROM Students_info AS tb1
GROUP BY tb1.stud_id , tb1.stud_name
ORDER BY total_marks DESC
```

I have also tried

```
ORDER BY (SELECT sum(score) FROM scores WHERE student_id = tb1.student) DESC
```

Assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with this? Does it run and not produce good results? Where is the question here?

Comment: agree with above comment - can we have additional details please? from what i gather - it sounds like what you are trying to do is a left join of your subquery to the first query. utilizing join and ON syntax instead of WHERE.

Answer (score 4):

I'm confused by your query, the select statement you are ordering by will return the same results for every student, because it's not related to the students_info table.

I assume you want something like this:

```
SELECT tb1.stud_id , tb1.stud_name , SUM(tb2.score) AS total_marks
FROM Students_info AS tb1
LEFT JOIN scores AS tb2
    ON tb1.stud_id = tb2.student_id
GROUP BY tb1.stud_id , tb1.stud_name
ORDER BY total_marks DESC
```

Comment: very similar to what i was thinking

Comment: +1 beat me to it :) And good job with the left join; exactly what's needed to duplicate the behavior in the original.

Comment: His subquery has a where clause in it based on the query data so it should not return the same results for each student. Also, I do not believe you can order by the field name you give to a calculated field unless you have derived the table.

Comment: You can order by alias in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I found nothing wrong with your query. Try this sql. It will work.

```
SELECT tb1.stud_id , tb1.stud_name , sum(tb2.score) AS total_marks 
FROM Students_info AS tb1
LEFT JOIN scores AS tb2
ON tb1.student_id=tb2.student_id
GROUP BY tb1.stud_id , tb1.stud_name
ORDER BY sum(tb2.score) DESC
```

Comment: This is more similar to what i have now. I still tho don't get why it dint work earlier when i used a sub query instead of a JOiN . Thanks.